# Bot Framework v4.0 : Can't execute my waterfall steps in my dialog

Tags: .net, botframework

I'm trying to create a root dialog in which the user choose between two options. Each option will redidrect the user to a dialog. The problem is that i create my waterfall steps in my dialog contructor but it's never executed.

The code in my root dialog is :

```
 public class GreetingDialog : ComponentDialog
    {
        // User state for greeting dialog
        private const string GreetingStateProperty = "greetingState";

        // Dialog IDs
        private const string ProfileDialog = "profileDialog";
        private static readonly List<string> _welcomeList = new List<string> { "All", "Typed" };

        public static IList<Choice> WelcomeChoices { get; } = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(_welcomeList);

        // <summary>Gets the reprompt action for the top-level dialog.</summary>
        public static Activity WelcomeReprompt
        {
            get
            {
                var reprompt = MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(_welcomeList, "Please choose an option");
                reprompt.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;
                return reprompt as Activity;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GreetingDialog"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="botServices">Connected services used in processing.</param>
        /// <param name="botState">The <see cref="UserState"/> for storing properties at user-scope.</param>
        /// <param name="loggerFactory">The <see cref="ILoggerFactory"/> that enables logging and tracing.</param>
        public GreetingDialog(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            : base(nameof(GreetingDialog))
        {
            // Add control flow dialogs
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                    InitializeStateStepAsync,
                    DisplayGreetingStateStepAsync,
            }; 
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(ProfileDialog, waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt("choicePrompt"));
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InitializeStateStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Greet the guest and ask them to choose an option.
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(
                "Welcome to Contoso Hotel and Resort.",
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "choicePrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Choose an option"),
                    RetryPrompt = WelcomeReprompt,
                    Choices = WelcomeChoices,
                },
                cancellationToken);
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DisplayGreetingStateStepAsync(
                                                    WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
                                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var context = stepContext.Context;

            // Display their profile information and end dialog.
            await context.SendActivityAsync($"end of greeting dialog!");
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }
    }
```

I can't figure how to execute my waterfall step nor how to get the choice result. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing an `OnTurnAsync` method which is required to run the bot.  Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt)  you will need to do something like this inside your onturn:

```
var dialogContext = await _dialogs.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);

if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
{
    await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync("details", null, cancellationToken);
}
```